# why the program omitted some lines? (c program to encrypt text)

Tags: c, encryption, command-line-arguments, caesar-cipher, vlab

i am trying to make a program that encrypt text with a Caesar cipher.The number of positions to shift will be given to the program as a command line argument and characters other than letters should not be encrypted. The program should stop only at the end of input. My issue is that the program omit the lines that mod the number. the program is run on a platform that provided by my school, i am not sure what it is. please kindly help me to fix the program.

here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
int num = atoi(argv[1]);
char caesar[100];
char ch;
int shift = num%26;
while ( fgets(caesar, 100, stdin) != NULL){
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(caesar); i++){
    ch = caesar[i];
    if( ch >= 97 && ch <= 122){
      if( ch + shift < 97){
      ch = ch + shift + 26;
      }
      else if( ch + shift > 122){
      ch = ch + shift - 26;
      }
      else{
      ch = ch + shift;
      }
      caesar[i] = ch;
    }
    else if( ch >= 65 && ch <= 90){
      if( ch + shift < 65){
      ch = ch + shift + 26;
      }
      else if( ch + shift > 90){
      ch = ch + shift - 26;
      }
      else{
      ch = ch +shift;
      }
      caesar[i] = ch;
    }
  }
}
printf("%s", caesar);

 return 0;
}
```

[here is some examples which have correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtY6l.png)
[here is what my program did. the program ignored shift = num%26 and i can't figure out why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjW9D.png)

Comment: What did lead you into this conclusion. Did you debug it?

Comment: if you add one printf - you will see that it is executing it : https://godbolt.org/z/q8TSqu

Comment: Well, to start, your `printf` is outside/after the outer `while` loop. So, you'll only print the _last_ line. Move the `printf` to the bottom of the `while` loop so that it does the print for each line